# How do I upgrade PHP on a Plesk system?

Tags: php, rhel5

We are running a few servers with Plesk 9.2. PHP is tightly integrated with Plesk, so I'm wary of updating it independently of Plesk.

The problem is that 9.2 ships with PHP 5.1, and I need 5.2.

What's the correct way to upgrade PHP on a Plesk system?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution seems to be the one provided here: http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/PHP

1. Add the Atomic repo:

   `wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic.sh | sh`
2. `yum upgrade`

Check step about `skip-bdb` on http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mysql

You may have to run `yum` with the `--nogpgcheck` flag if it gives you problems with installing unsigned RPMs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two instances of PHP associated with Plesk.  One is for Plesk admin's interface and the other for vhosts. You can't upgrade the admin PHP because it is very tightly integrated with Plesk, but you *can* easily upgrade the vhost PHP with the usual OS upgrade utilities like yum, apt-get, up2date, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is maybe also that you don't have yum installed on your centos 5 - then visit [openvz](http://wiki.openvz.org/Install_yum). This is no spam message - this was really the issue for me and I want to help anyone who'll have this problem.